# Python if else statement not passing or not reading txt

Tags: python, text

I am counting the number of rows in a file "Index40".  There are 11,436 rows.  I save that number in a txt file as a string.  What I want my code to do is count the number of rows in this file each night and if is equal to the number stored as a single string value I want the script to end, otherwise rewrite the number in the text file and continue on with the script.  The problem Im having is the script always thinks the row count is not equal to the txt value.  Here is the code:

```
lyrfile = r"C:\Hubble\Cimage_Project\MapData.gdb\Index40"
result = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(lyrfile).getOutput(0))
textResult = str(result)
with open(r'C:\Hubble\Cimage_Project\Index40Count.txt', 'r+') as a:
    if a == textResult:
        pass  
    else:
        a.write(textResult)
        #then do a bunch more code
        print "not passing"
```

Comment: Why not `if a != textResult:` and omit the `else:`?

Comment: The script always thinks its not equal.  It thinks a = <open file 'C:\Hubble\Cimage_Project\Index40Count.txt', mode 'r+' at 0x109BCB78> so there for its not equal and will always continue.

Comment: You're comparing a string to a file object. You'll need to actually read from the file.

Comment: @Wooble3 I tried this `with open(r'C:\Hubble\Cimage_Project\Index40Count.txt', 'r+') as a:
    for line in a:
        if line == result:
            pass  

        else:
            a.write(textResult)
            #then do a bunch more code` but it still thinks its not equal and then instead of writing over it adds to the string like this 1143611436

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're comparing `textResult` with `a`, which is the *file object*.

If you want the contents of the file, you'll need to read from the file object, e.g. `a.read()` to get the entire contents of the file as a string.

So I think you're looking for something like this:

```
with open(r'C:\Hubble\Cimage_Project\Index40Count.txt', 'r+') as a:
    contents = a.read() # read the entire file
    if contents != textResult:
        a.seek( 0 ) # seek back to the beginning of the file
        a.truncate() # truncate in case the old value was longer than the new value
        a.write(textResult)
        #then do a bunch more code
        print "not passing"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a "row" is a string that ends with a new-line character (therefore, a "row" is a "line" in your file), you can do this to get the total number of rows and use that to compare with your initial row count

```
with open(r'C:\Hubble\Cimage_Project\Index40Count.txt', 'r+') as f:
    allLines = f.readlines() # get all lines
    rowCount = len(allLines) # get length of all lines
    if rowCount == result:
        # do something when they are equal
    else:
        # do something when they are not equal
```

Comment: What I'd really prefer to do is write the date/time and count in two different columns so I can track the daily results and have the textResult compare to the value in the bottom row of the count column!   Not totally necessary but cool to have